# Css problem with a div

Tags: html, css, webkit, tumblr

Hey I'm developing this layout for a future site of mine but I can't modify id=titre since I've added a a container div with rotation transformation.....   Here is the code

```
  <style type="text/css">
body {
     background-color: white;
}

.rotate {

 /* Rotate div */
transform:rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Opera */
background-color: transparent;
 position: fixed;

 margin-left: 1100px;

}
 #titre {
      font-family: baskerville;
      color: blue;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-style: italic bold;
 }
 #description {
          font-family: baskerville;
          font-style: italic
          text-transform: underline;
          color: #000;
          }



 </style>
  <div class="rotate">                     <!--Bloc devant aller à droite -->
    <div id="titre">                                   
     <h1>{Title}</h1>                         
    </div>    
   <div id=description">                         
    {block:Description}
        <p id="description">{Description}</p>
     {/block:Description}
   </div>
  </div>
```

Can you see where my problem is ?

Comment: You can't have a division *and* a paragraph with the ID 'description', and you're missing a double quote in the division.

Comment: Argh. Yet another piece of code using the same ID more than once. _When will they learn_.

Answer (score 2):

ID in html elements should be Unique.

You have 2 elements with the id=description.

Use:

```
class="description"
```

instead. (if you want to apply a style to multiple elements)

Answer (score 0):

Using the same ID for two different elements on the same page is a big no-no.

Give them unique IDs and give them a common, matching class.

```
class="description"
```